# Como recolher a altura de um elemento com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Opa, não estou conseguindo recolher a altura de um objeto do documento.

Tenho um slider, que funciona com `ul > li` (talvez seja relevante), e dentro de um slide `<li>`, estou colocando via javascript e c# três divs, cada uma com uma imagem dentro.
O que eu preciso é recolher a altura que a imagem foi renderizada. Já tentei de várias maneiras acessar, mas parece que o javascript não consegue recolher os dados em tempo de execução...

Já tentei:

```
$("foo").height();
$("foo").naturalHeight(); // nesse caso eu teria uma solução "budget" para o caso
$("foo").outerHeight();
```

Depois de armazenar os dados, eu preciso dar um set em outra div de acordo com o resultado encontrado.

```
$("#noticias").css("height", fullHeight);
```

Já tentei também dar um timeout depois de alimentar as divs criadas pelo c#, mas também não resolveu. A questão é: Existe alguma coisa que me ajude a recolher dados em tempo de execução? Entre js e jQuery?

Agradeço qualquer sugestão.

Comment: Pode juntar um exemplo no jsFiddle? o que experimentou é correto, não percebo o que possa estar a falhar.

Comment: Muito complicado, além dos dados virem do c#, como citado, estou usando bootstrap e mais o plugin do slider...

Comment: Tem um link live? Se não vai ser difícil... já tentou com `element.offsetHeight` ou `element.getBouningClientRect().height` ou mesmo `window.getComputedStyle(element).height`?

Comment: Nenhum destes, vou testar estes aqui, pior que está tudo em servidor local :/ Ja posto o resultado dos testes.

Comment: Loga no console a altura da imagem. Veja se está retornando o valor. Faça isso com o height(). Caso ele nao retorne nada o problema está na identificação do elemento. Como o @sergio disse é meio complicado ajudar a cegas assim.

Comment: Fizemos algumas experiências e ficou claro que o problema está no tempo de execução. Testei com um sleep de 500 e deu certo.

Comment: Neste caso tente utilizar um setInterval ou setTimeout recursivo, que verifique se o valor é um valor válido de acordo com suas regras. Outra solução é criar um EventListener e disparar este evento do C#. 
Ou mesmo usar algo genérico como quando a página estiver carregada `$(document).ready(function(){ //code });`

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque não é claro o problema e não é possível de reproduzr.

Comment: Faz um exemplo no Fiddle que represente seu HTML já renderizado.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, você tem várias imagens de alturas **distintas**. Ao trocar a imagem no slider, você quer que o slider **adquira** a altura da imagem atual, correto?

Answer (score 3):

Verifique por favor se o seguinte código resolve o seu problema:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    console.log($("#foo").outerHeight());
});
```

Penso que a imagem não estará carregada no momento em que tenta calcular a altura da mesma.

Answer (score 1):

fiz um teste aqui p/ você, é assim que eu faço, provavelmente você não esta conseguindo executar o que quer por algum motivo "depois" de já ter setado a altura.

```js
$('#foo').click(function(){
    var altura = $(this).height();
    $('#noticias').css('height', altura);
});
```

```css
#foo{width: 150px; height: 150px; background: blue;
color: white;}
#noticias{width: 150px; height:50px; background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'>clique aki</div>
<br><br><br>
<div id='noticias'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você for passar as infos em C#, passe usando a seguinte função:

```
string html_para_passar = "<script>$('#id').appendTo('#id_2');</script>"; //no caso aqui usando jQuery
RegisterStartupScript("", html_para_passar);
```